# Где разместить рекламу на StackOverflow?

Tags: поддержка, реклама

Где на stackoverflow размещается реклама?

Answer (score 5):

Внизу есть ссылка [Связаться с нами](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact), там в комбобоксе выбираете «Я хочу разместить рекламу на StackExchange».

Answer (score 4):

Цитата из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion):

> Наши расценки на рекламу довольно гуманные; подробнее вы можете узнать у нашего [отдела по продаже рекламы](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact). Также мы предлагаем [бесплатные рекламные объявления](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) в сообществе для проектов с открытым кодом и для некоммерческих организаций.

Подробнее о продвижении собственных продуктов на сайтах сети StackExchange:

- [Можно ли осуществлять поддержку моего продукта на данном сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)
- [Как не быть спамером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)
- [Описание метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0/info) [реклама](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3):

На данный момент, на Stack Overflow на русском нельзя разместить рекламу. В обозримом будущем мы планируем провести опрос для размещения рекламы сообщества [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) на бесплатной основе.